# How to call a c++ function with byte* and int* parameters from C# through a CLI/C++ wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am trying to call c++ functions from my C# class through a CLI/C++ wrapper class. I was able to call function with char* parameter using marshaling. But how can i do same for parameter int*.

```
//My Native Class
class UNMANAGEDLIB_API CUnmanagedLib {
public:
    CUnmanagedLib(void);
public: void PrintMessage(char* message)
{
    CString StrMessage = message;
    MessageBox(NULL, StrMessage, L"Test Message", MB_OK);
}
public:void IncrementBy2(int* myval)
{
    myval = myval + 2;
}
};

//Wrapper Class
#pragma once
#include "..\UnmanagedLib\UnmanagedLib.h";
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
namespace NativeCodeWrapper {
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public: void SendMessageWrapper(String^ strMessage)
    {
        CUnmanagedLib instance;
        char* str2 = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strMessage);
        instance.PrintMessage(str2);
    }

    public: void IncrementBy2Wrapper(int* myval)
    {
        CUnmanagedLib instance;
        instance.IncrementBy2(myval);
    }
    };
}

//C# Call
NativeCodeWrapper.Class1 cls = new NativeCodeWrapper.Class1();
//This Works fine
cls.SendMessageWrapper("Hello");

int i = 0;
//How to pass parameter
cls.IncrementBy2Wrapper(???????);
```

Thanks

Comment: Declare the parameter as `int% myval` to make it easy in C#.  That still doesn't allow you to pass the pointer to native code, myval might be a field in a managed object and the GC might move the object while the native code is running.  Use a temporary that can't be moved: int temp = myval; cls.IncrementBy2Wrapper(&temp); myval = temp;

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the "IncrementBy2" method defined in the native code is incorrect.

```cpp
public:void IncrementBy2(int* myval)
{
    myval = myval + 2;
}
```

*The aforementioned operation adds two to the variable's stated parameter address.*
If you desire to alter the variable;

```cpp
public:void IncrementBy2(int* myval)
{
    *myval = *myval + 2;
    // Or
    // *myval += 2;
}
```

Have you tried the "IncrementBy2Wrapper" method parameter with "int%"?

```cs
public: void IncrementBy2Wrapper(int% myval)
{
    CUnmanagedLib instance;
    instance.IncrementBy2((int*)(int&)myval);
}
```

```cs
int i = 0;
//How to pass parameter
//cls.IncrementBy2Wrapper(???????);
cls.IncrementBy2Wrapper(ref i);
```